# How do I drag/drop html table columns?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a html table. I want to drag/drop columns, not rows. I am using vue.js.

It's easy to drag/drop rows, because each row has its own parent element where you can pass `draggable="true"`.  As for columns, each  is contained within it's parent which is row. So I can't pass native `draggable="true"` to the whole column of the table.

I then found this library: https://github.com/kutlugsahin/vue-smooth-dnd, but this doesn't give me the column dragging option.

How can I achieve what I want? would be better if it's possible using the above plugin.

Comment: where you able to resolve your problem with below answer?

Comment: No. didn't try it. looks like it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using a table from Element UI and wrote a custom method to setup drag&drop:

```
initializeDragAndDropFunctionality() {
  const tableColumn = this.$refs.tableRef.$el.querySelector(
    '.el-table__header-wrapper .el-table__header thead tr'
  );
  Sortable.create(tableColumn, {
    draggable: 'th',
    onEnd: this.dragReorderColumn
  });
}
```

It is called on mount of the Component:

```
  mounted() {
    this.initializeTable();
  },
```

In the table you need to set a value for ref:

```
  <el-table
      ref="tableRef"
    >
      <el-table-column
        v-for="(column, index) in tableTitles"
        :label="column.title"
        :prop="column.field"
        :width="column.width"
      >
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
```

The component imports a util class which uses Sortablejs:

```
import Sortable from 'sortablejs';

const vueSortable = {
  ...Sortable,
  create(el, options) {
    function swap(draggableSelector, movedElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
      const parent = movedElement.parentNode;
      const cells = parent.querySelectorAll(draggableSelector);

      if (oldIndex > newIndex) {
        parent.insertBefore(movedElement, cells[newIndex]);
      } else {
        // inserts after trs[oldIndex] - if nextSibling is null insertBefore puts item to the end
        parent.insertBefore(movedElement, cells[newIndex].nextSibling);
      }
    }

    const tmpStorage = {};

    const newOptions = {
      ...options,
      onEnd(evt) {
        swap(options.draggable, evt.item, evt.newIndex, evt.oldIndex);

        tmpStorage.onChange = undefined;

        if (options.onEnd) {
          try {
            options.onEnd(evt);
          } catch (ex) {
            console.error('Error at onEnd:', ex);
          }
        }
      }
    };

    return Sortable.create(el, newOptions);
  }
};

export default vueSortable;
```

Comment: Hi @Simon, thanks for the great answer! I am new in Vuejs, and this answer helped me a lot.
about the util class vueSortable file, did you mean that instead of import Sortable library in the component, the util vueSortable file will be imported. Could you please have a example on github or codepen?

Answer (score 1):

I also want to drag a column in table. I found this solution. All you need to do is to reorder the thead key and the data will be rerendered.

```
<el-table border :data="tableData" size="mini" >
      <el-table-column
        v-for="(item, index) in elTheadList"
        :prop="dataTheadList[index]"
        :label='item'
        :key="`thead_${index}`"
       >
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
data() {
    return {
      tableData: [{
        date: '2016-05-01',
        name: 'Cristian Millan',
        address: 'Baja #11'
      },{
        date: '2016-05-02',
        name: 'Jorge Cabrera',
        address: 'Progreso #18'
      },{
        date: '2016-05-03',
        name: 'Armando Mendivil',
        address: 'Novena #12'
      }],
      dataTheadList: [
        'date',
        'name',
        'address'
      ],
      elTheadList: ['Date', 'Name', 'Address'],
    }
  },

mounted() {
   const el = document.querySelector('.el-table__header-wrapper tr')
   this.sortable = Sortable.create(el, {
    animation: 180,
    delay: 0,
    onEnd: evt => {
      const oldItem = this.dataTheadList[evt.oldIndex]
      this.dataTheadList.splice(evt.oldIndex, 1)
      this.dataTheadList.splice(evt.newIndex, 0, oldItem)
    }
  })
  }
```